# formaldehyde strong odor neutralization

Tags: everyday-chemistry, applied-chemistry

One of our customers used a very high dose of formaldehyde 37% solution (60 liter formaldehyde  in 40 liter water) for disinfection in  his chicken farm (saloon). Now he says the odor of formaldehyde is very strong and can`t start breeding  season.  How can I help her?

Can he  neutralize  formaldehyde odor with some chemical treatment? Maybe he can use sodium hypochlorite (bleach). Do you think chlorine can oxidize formaldehyde?

Comment: Just use water and a fan. Bleach will react exothermically and may start a fire.

Comment: No, you don't want to add more water unless you can wash it away. Dampness will "hold" the formaldehyde. This seems to be inside, so you want to use a fan and increase the temperature to dry the place out.

Comment: Many tanks I suggest her washing Evey think with water ,and increasing temperature ,when I have report inform you @quantum American

Answer (score 2):

Ammonia water, AKA ammonium hydroxide ($\ce{NH4OH}$), [reacts with formaldehyde to form hexamine](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01191a034?journalCode=jacsat), a comparatively innocuous solid (though it is flammable when dry).

Safer might be [*Neutralization of Formaldehyde Gas by Ammonium Bicarbonate and Ammonium Carbonate*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.163.6694&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which would greatly reduce the flammability of the product.